# Apply attribute-sets on existing elements

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

Working with a imported JSON data with a relatively flat hierarchical tree structure.
In the current code I am applying attribute-sets during the creation of elements.

Is it possible to create all the elements first and after that apply the attribute-sets?
It seems "use-attribute-sets" is an attribute, thus need to be added onto a element to work.

There are no error messages in my current code.

I am just looking to see if possible to do things in certain sequence as described below.
The reason for this planned change is to handle a bigger data volume thus perform the parsing and creation of element first, and only after that step, perform a unified way of adding attributes through attribute-sets.

The sequence I have:

```
[1] Create attribute sets. 
[2] Group element names. 
[3] Parse JSON to XML map. 
[4] Build element, using attribute-sets and extract key value
```

The sequence I would like to perform:

```
[1] Create attribute sets (same as above).
[2] Group element names (same as above).
[3] Parse JSON to XML map (same as above).
[4] Build element names with corresponding key (split of above bullet 4).
[5] Add attribute-set based on template match in the code (split of above bullet 4).
```

**JSON:**

```
<data>
{
  "store": {
    "pencils": 43,
    "milk": 21,
    "rulers": 12,
    "beer": 17
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:inventory="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/2"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- [1] Create attribute sets -->

  <xsl:attribute-set name="group-office">
    <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">office</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <!-- [2] Group element names-->

  <xsl:param name="group-office">pencils, rulers</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="attributes-for-group-office" select="tokenize($group-office, ',\s*')"/>

  <!-- [3] Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <inventory:store>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
      </inventory:store>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- [4] Build element, using attribute-sets and extract key value -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']/*[@key = $attributes-for-group-office]">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:element name="item:{@key}" use-attribute-sets="group-office">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**
(current and how it should look like after sequence change of code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory:store xmlns:inventory="http://www.example.org/1"
                 xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/2">
   <item:pencils contextRef="office">43</item:pencils>
   <item:rulers contextRef="office">12</item:rulers>
</inventory:store>
```

Comment: The use of `<xsl:for-each select=".">` as the child of `xsl:template match` seems rather pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a rather artificial and not really easy separation as you can't inject an attribute set without creating an element so all you could do, if that helps, write a template with high-priority to select the element name and pass it on to a lower one that expects that name as a parameter and then do the real work, like before, to create the element with the attribute set:

```
  <!-- [4] Extract key value for element name -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']/*[@key = $attributes-for-group-office]" priority="10">
    <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="element-name" select="'item:' || @key"/>
    </xsl:next-match>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- [5] Build element and add attribute-set based on template match in the code -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']/*[@key = $attributes-for-group-office]" priority="5">
    <xsl:param name="element-name" required="yes"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$element-name}" use-attribute-sets="group-office">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

I am not sure that separation makes any sense but for the time being I can't think of anything else if you really want two separate templates. Of course the mode based suggestion by Siebe with a temporary tree is also an option but needs that temporary tree; or you could use the above and instead of relying on priorities to ensure the order of processing use a mode and push the same node through, for me it feels like the artificial and difficult separation as before:

```
  <!-- [4] Build element and extract key value -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']/*[@key = $attributes-for-group-office]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="add-attribute-sets">
      <xsl:with-param name="element-name" select="'item:' || @key"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- [5] Build element and add attribute-set based on template match in the code -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']/*[@key = $attributes-for-group-office]" mode="add-attribute-sets">
    <xsl:param name="element-name" required="yes"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$element-name}" use-attribute-sets="group-office">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use modes, like this (Added some elements to make the wanted stages clear):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:inventory="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/2"
  expand-text="yes"
  >
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:mode name="useAttributeSet" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <!-- [1] Create attribute sets -->
  
  <xsl:attribute-set name="group-office">
    <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">office</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>
  
  <!-- [2] Group element names-->
  
  <xsl:param name="group-office">pencils, rulers</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="attributes-for-group-office" select="tokenize($group-office, ',\s*')"/>
  
  <!-- [3] Parse JSON to XML -->
  
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:variable name="withoutAttributeSets">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <stages>
      <stage>
        <inventory:store>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$withoutAttributeSets"/>
        </inventory:store>
      </stage>
      <stage>
        <inventory:store>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$withoutAttributeSets" mode="useAttributeSet"/>
        </inventory:store>
      </stage>
    </stages>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- [4] Build element names with corresponding key (split of above bullet 4). -->
  
  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'store']/*[@key = $attributes-for-group-office]">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:element name="item:{@key}" >
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- [5] Add attribute-set based on template match in the code (split of above bullet 4). -->

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = $attributes-for-group-office]" mode="useAttributeSet">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" use-attribute-sets="group-office">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

This wil give this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stages xmlns:inventory="http://www.example.org/1"
        xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/2">
   <stage>
      <inventory:store>
         <item:pencils>43</item:pencils>
         <item:rulers>12</item:rulers>
      </inventory:store>
   </stage>
   <stage>
      <inventory:store>
         <item:pencils contextRef="office">43</item:pencils>
         <item:rulers contextRef="office">12</item:rulers>
      </inventory:store>
   </stage>
</stages>
```

Adjust it to your needs.

If you would like to reuse this [4]-stage some other way you also could save it like this:

```
<xsl:result-document href="stage-4.xml">
  <inventory:store>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$withoutAttributeSets"/>
  </inventory:store>
</xsl:result-document>
```